# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() can't rate at the new App version

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

In version 1.0, users can rate the app without a problem.
However, in version 2.0, the rating box does not appear

The function called to show the rating box is the same in both versions:

```
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

Answer (score 8):

Why the rate box is not shown? Possible reasons:

1. When building in Xсode, the rating box is shown.
2. When building from a CI solution for release, the rating box is **NOT** shown.
3. When running from TestFlight, the rating box is **NOT** shown.
4. When running from the AppStore, only users who purchased (free or paid) your app will see it.
5. When running from the AppStore, users who obtain your app via Connect promo codes will **NOT** see it.
6. If a user leaves a rating, the app can not show the rating box for at least a year afterwards and after a new version has been released.
7. Apps can only prompt users for a rating or review three times in a year regardless of the version number updates.
8. Users are also given more control about whether they want to be asked to review apps at all. In Settings, there is a global switch to suppress these alerts from ever appearing (Settings → iTunes & App Store → In-App Ratings & Reviews).

Comment: Can you please provide a link/source where you found this information?

Comment: @liefersfl https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/

Comment: I don't think the above link covers all of the above points e.g. point 2 (when building from a CI solution for release, the rating box is not shown)

Answer (score 1):

Apple has explicitly limited how often the rating box can be shown to users. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> The user can supply feedback or dismiss the prompt with a single tap. (In Settings, the user can also opt out of receiving these rating prompts for all apps they have installed.) **The system automatically limits the display of the prompt to three occurrences per app within a 365-day period**.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/ratings-and-reviews) for more information

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/